# while loop is empty php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

```
    <?PHP 

require "connect.php";
$sql = "SELECT `url` FROM `laatsteberichten` ORDER BY `datum` DESC LIMIT 2";
mysql_query ($sql) or  die (mysql_error());
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

echo("<b>$data[0]</b><br>");
}  
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

This script i'm using 4 times on my website.

- To show 10 articles from the same category at the end of every article.

To show 10 random articles at the end of every article, except the category where the article is listed in

To show the 7 most viewed articles in the sidebar
To show the 3 newest articles in the sidebar

It works perfect for the first 3
But the last one showing only a blank bar. (for 3 newest articles)
Source code is : `<b><br></b><b><br></b><b><br></b><b><br></b><b><br></b>`

Can anybody help me, or let me know how I can check whats the problem?

Comment: I suggest you to use mysqli instead of mysql first

Comment: Sorry source code is `code` <b><br></b><b><br></b><b><br></b><b><br></b><b><br></b> `code`

Comment: What is the code than?

Comment: are you getting any error?....before ensure use mysqli

Comment: go through with this http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Answer (score 0):

**These Code Will Be Checked**

```
require "connect.php";
$sql = "SELECT 'url' FROM 'laatsteberichten' ORDER BY 'datum' DESC LIMIT 2";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or  die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
echo "<b>$data['url']</b>";
}  
mysql_close($connect);
```